# Add actionbutton in a dropdown menu , how do I know if the button was clicked in shiny

Tags: shinydashboard, shiny-server, shinyjs

Like to know if a button was clicked or how integrate the actionButton of shiny need to know if a option was selected then used to run something

New using shiny, just want to do a easy dashboard

```
library(shiny)

library(bs4Dash)
```

```
ui <- 
    bs4DashPage(
        enable_preloader = TRUE,
        navbar = bs4DashNavbar(border = FALSE,
                               rightUi = HTML('<div class="dropdown">
                                              <button class = "btn btn-outline-primary dropdown-toggle"
                                                      type  = "button"
                                                      id    = "dropdownMenuButton"
                                                      data-toggle ="dropdown" 
                                                      aria-haspopup="true" 
                                                      aria-expanded="false">
                                                      Período de Consulta
                                                      </button>
                                              <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right"  aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                                                <button id = "yr_anterior"  class="dropdown-item" type="button">Año Pasado</button>
                                                <button id = "mes_anterior" class="dropdown-item" type="button">Mes Pasado</button>
                                                <button id = "sem_anterior" class="dropdown-item" type="button">Ultima Semana</button>
                                              </div>
                                            </div>')),
        sidebar = bs4DashSidebar(title = "Opciones",skin = "light",status = "info",brandColor = "primary"),
        
        footer = bs4DashFooter(),
        title = "test",
        body = bs4DashBody(
            textOutput("valor")
        )
    )
```

```
server <- function(input, output,session) {
observeEvent(input$yr_anterior,{
    output$valor <- renderText("hola")})
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the function `pickerInput` from `shinyWidgets` package can generate what you are looking for. You can use it like this with the labels in your example, and `input$InputMenu` gives the selected option on your `server` function

```
pickerInput(inputId = 'InputMenu',
            choices = c("Período de Consulta","Año Pasado","Mes Pasado","Ultima Semana"),
            options = list(style = "btn-outline-primary dropdown-toggle") )
```

or adding a label instead of that first choice `label="Período de Consulta:"`